# How can you predict whether an object is going to rotate? (question about torque)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque

I know a torque causes angular acceleration, but the derivation for the formula $\tau = I \alpha$ seems to assume the object is going to rotate in the first place, as it uses the identity $a_{tan} = R \alpha$, which is true for bodies in rotation. So it seems the torque only gives information about the angular acceleration, *given that rotation takes place*. But how can you predict if rotation will take place?

Comment: We predict very less in physics.

Answer (score 0):

Rotation will take place about a point if the algebraic sum of the moments (torques) about the point is greater than zero so that you no longer have static equilibrium.

Take the simple example of using a wrench to tighten a bolt. You apply a force perpendicular to the wrench handle creating a clockwise torque (moment) that turns the bolt. There is a net clockwise torque acting on the bolt.

As the bolt tightens a counter clockwise torque (moment) reaction at the interface of bolt and material it goes into develops, opposing your torque. Eventually you are unable to apply a clockwise torque great enough to oppose the counter clockwise reaction torque and turn the bolt any further. The net torque is zero, and the bolt stops turning.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

${\tau}=I{\alpha}$ is the rotational analogue of the equation $F=ma$. Just like how acceleration will only be there if there is an unbalanced force on the body, angular acceleration will only exist if there is net torque. It is not possible for torque to not produce rotation in a body.

Hence it is justified to assume that torque will cause angular acceleration because if there was no rotation, net torque would be zero.

Answer (score 0):

If an object is not rotating, then the angular velocity is a constant (zero).  Given the velocity is a constant, that means the acceleration is zero.

Therefore for any non-rotating object, you must be able to conclude that the sum of all torques is zero.

$$ \tau_{net} = \alpha I = 0 $$